# Как работает shared lock в Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine2

Допустим есть класс Group(группа как на vk.com). Group может иметь 10000 альбомов(альбомов с фотографиями естественно).
В Group также есть создатель и админы. Они могут добавлять, изменять и удалять альбомы.
Для работы с БД я использую Doctrine2. С optimistic lock и pessimistic write(exclusive lock) я разобрался. Но с pessimistic read(shared lock) еще нет.
Допустим два админа одновременно решили создать альбом когда в группе уже есть 9999 альбомов. Одновременно на сервере будет выполнен один и тот самый скрипт, в котором из БД будет извлечен объект Group, внутри метода Group::createAlbum будет проверено количество альбомов, если их меньше чем 10000, то альбом будет создан. Вот так примерно выглядит createAlbum:

```
function createAlbum(...) {
    if($this->albumsCount === 10000) {
        // альбом НЕ создаётся
    }

    // альбом создаётся 
}
```

Так вот, я хочу разобраться с shared lock, но всё что я понял, то это только то, что при shared lock допускается, чтобы параллельные транзакции могли читать одну и ту же запись в БД. Но только та транзакция, которая первая захватила shared lock, может изменять запись, а остальные должны ждать пока она не освободит эту запись.

Я хочу удостовериться, что решения не будут приниматься на основе устаревших данных, то есть инварианты будут соблюдены. Короче говоря, нужно избежать подобную ситуацию:

В Group уже 9999 альбомов. Два админа создают альбом и выполняются две транзакции, пускай это будут транзакции A и B.
В транзакции A извлекается Group из БД, в Group::createAlbum выполняется проверка

```
if($this->albumsCount === 10000)
```

Поскольку альбомов 9999, то альбом создаётся, а $albumsCount увеличивается на единицу.
Но пока транзакция A еще не закончилась, в транзакции B также извлекается та же самая Group из БД, затем происходит проверка:

```
if($this->albumsCount === 10000)
```

Но поскольку B прочитала еще НЕ измененные данные, то $albumsCount === 9999, поэтому новый альбом создаётся и $albumsCount увеличивается на единицу.
Транзакция A обновляет запись в БД и завершается. Всё ок, но затем транзакция B делает то же самое и альбом из транзакции A пропадает. Конец.

Так вот, я хочу чтобы в транзакции B была произведена проверка

```
if($this->albumsCount === 10000)
```

только после того как транзакция A уже закончилась. Я склоняюсь к тому, что такое возможно только при exclusive lock, потому что там запрещено даже чтение залоченой записи. Но также вероятно, что я неправильно понял как shared lock реализован в Doctrine, мало инфы толковой и разжеванной об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пессимистичные блокировки представлены как явные блокировки SQL уровня:

- shared lock = `select ... for share`
- exclusive lock = `select ... for update`

> Но только та транзакция, которая первая захватила shared lock, может изменять запись, а остальные должны ждать пока она не освободит эту запись.

Это неверно. Попытаться захватить блокировку более высокого уровня может любая транзакция. Но она будет ждать завершение всех транзакций (кроме самой себя) которые ранее взяли `for share` блокировку.

При этом в ситуации:

```
t1: share
t2: share
t2: update
t1: update
```

Вы получите `deadlock` и одна из транзакций будет принудительно отменена.

Если вы хотите прочитать значение чтобы затем его изменить - вам нужна `for update` блокировка. Без этого у вас не будет однозначной сериализации транзакций.

`for share` блокировка же нужна когда вы хотите быть уверенный что за время выполнения транзакции строка не изменялась, но корректности вашей транзакции никак не мешает то что кто-то прочитает эту же строку параллельно с вашей транзакцией.

Для `for share` полезный пример мне привести сложно, обычно этим пренебрегают и не выставляют явную блокировку вообще. Например, можно взять `for share` блокировку на Group в начале транзакции чтобы эта группа не была удалена пока вы добавляете альбом.

Comment: Я понял где я ступил. Также понял о чём вы написали, хотя было сложно). Я попробовал следующее: транзакция A ставит shared lock, затем искуственно приостанавливается, транзакция B ставит shared lock. Транзакция А возобновляется, но обновить запись не может потому что B держит shared lock, который не разрешает транзакции A получить exclusive lock и из-за этого в транзакции A происходит исключение, а B выполняется. Всё как вы и написали.
Верно я понял, что A не может получить exclusive lock из-за того, что B поставила shared lock?
И вообще, судя по всему, лучше использовать exclusive lock. Да?

Comment: `A не может получить exclusive lock из-за того, что B поставила shared lock` - да, поэтому A будет ждать пока не завершится B. А брать нужно ту блокировку, которая нужна по логике транзакции для корректной сериализации.